# Attaching a property to a javsacript function - Where does the property gets linked?

Tags: javascript

Please take a look at this following nsnippet of simple code:-

```
function Fis(){
}

Fis.num =20;//no errors
console.log(Fis.num);//prints  20
```

Now, I know that the Fis function is implicitly(from the very beginning) linked to  an object through "Fis.prototype" link.

In the code Fis.num = 20 is getting executed without any errors. Where is this num property getting linked ?

Comment: Functions are Objects, so they behave like Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Fis()` function is actually an object to which you can assign properties. In your case you define the `num` property with value `20` to `Fis`. So you link this property when you assign it to `Fis` with `Fis.num=20`. Therefore you can get the property value by `Fis.num`.

Comment: … and this has nothing to do with the prototype chain. The function is an object. You can set a property on the function because it is an object.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, every function is an object:

```js
var fn = function () {};
fn.foo = 'bar'; // add property to object
for (var index in fn) {
  // read properties from object
  if (fn.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
    console.log(fn[index]);
  }
}
```

In addition to that, every function object has a `prototype` property, which is an object itself. When you call a function the normal way, this `prototype` property has no effect. But when you call the function using `new`, JS creates a new object, whose prototype is the function's `prototype` property. Then it calls the function with the newly created object and returns it:

```js
var Func = function (baz) {
  console.log(this.foo + baz); // "barabc"
}

Func.prototype.foo = "bar";

var object = new Func("abc");
```

In this case, the function is also called the constructor of a class, an the new object is called an instance of this class.

Read more about the prototype chain on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).